# Ограничение доступа к интерфейсу DBus

Tags: c++, linux, qt, debian, qt5

Начал изучать работу межпроцессного взаимодействия с помощью **DBus** в **Qt**. Начал с примера **ping-pong**.

Возник вопрос: а как ограничить доступ к интерфейсу? Допустим **ACL** навешать, или как-то ещё. Чтоб, например, можно было подключиться к интерфейсу только процессам, запущенным от определённого юзера.

Comment: на сессионную шину ЕМНИП и так можно подключиться только от текущего пользователя и root'а. А на системную всей этой радостью заведует такой тёмный набор конфигов как polkit.

Comment: поправлю себя... `dbus` просто обеспечивает доставку сообщения, а программа уже сама решает, как на него реагировать. Один из способов сделать это централизовано — polkit.